# How to reconnect database to existing wordpress multisite setup after changing site name

Tags: multisite, database

I was formatted my laptop due some reasons and before that I was took backup for database and wordress setup of my site. Now after installation of my laptop I installed a fresh Xampp again.

After this I done following things:

1. I opened database backup in text editor and replaced "Old site Name" by "New Site Name".
2. Then I opened wp-config.php and replaced "old site name" by "new site name".
3. Then I replaced "new site name" against "old site name" from .htaccess file.
4. Then I created new database with "new site name" and uploaded old sql database to it. And its uploaded successfully without any issue.
5. Then I installed newly edited wordpress multisite setup to htdocs in xampp folder.

And checked the new site url on browser but it is showing white page only; neither site nor error.

Please, help me to install my site again with new name.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was performed all things right. And when I checked http://localhost/mysite/wp-config, it was working well only my home page was showing white page. Other sites in multisite wordpress setup was working good.

I just login my site, went to site network and edited the site title which I was changed before install. Then I just changed the theme again. I published properly with older theme.

My question is also an answer for the same question.